# How can I detect if a React component is completely loaded to show ot to hide a section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`ProfilePage` is a react component who display the profile of a user. When I call this component I want to display a `<Skeleton.Image/>` until the page and its contents are completely loaded. Please, how can I detect if the component is completely loaded and data are completely retrieved?

```
class ProfilePage extends Component {

  state = {
    all_currency: [],
    still_uploading: true,
    ....
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAccountData(this.props.match.params)

    api.post("/base/getAllCurrency", {}).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        all_currency: res.data.doc
      })
    })

    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad); // <===
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad); // <===
  }

  handleLoad = () => {
    this.setState({
      still_uploading: false
    })
  }
}
```

I use the state of the `still_uploading` to show or to hide the skeleton component.

```
{still_uploading && <Skeleton.Image/>}
```

**PS:** This program works only if I reload the page, but if I went to an other page, and return back to my page, the variable `still_uploading` will always have `true` value, and the `handleLoad()` function is never call back again. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

**I also tried to replace:**

```
window.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
```

by:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.handleLoad);
```

This one with `ReactDOM` never calls the function `handleLoad` even if I reload the page

Please, do you have any idea how to fix it? 

Regards

Comment: Do you display the response from `/base/getAllCurrency` on this Profile Page? If yes, I feel that your `still_uploading` state should be dependent on this response rather than the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `/base/getAllCurrency` return only the currencies form database, I use the resources to fill a list of currencies. They are others who retrieve other infos of the user, I delete them from this exemple to make is simple to understand

Comment: Well, in that case, I feel that the `still_uploading` state should depend on all those factors rather than `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Thanks again! Do you think this is the best solution? They are no function who detect if a component is completely loaded?

Comment: What does "completely loaded" mean? A component is completely loaded when it is mounted and initially rendered. If you want to fetch some data *after* it's mounted you can do that and in the meantime conditionally render some "loading" state until your state is populated from the asynchronous request. Just set `still_uploading` false in a `.finally` block of the Promise chain so when the POST request resolves/rejects your loading state will finalize.

Comment: Did you try to implement using my answer? @Joe

Comment: Yes @TaghiKhavari it's a good solution too! Thank you so much for your efforts!

Comment: @Joe Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always prefer `Function Component` to `Class Component` it's cleaner, faster and more readable. just change your code to something like this:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage(props) {
  const [all_currency, setAllCurrencies] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    getAccountData(params);

    api.post("/base/getAllCurrency", {}).then((res) => {
      setLoading(false);
      setAllCurrencies(res.data.doc);
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <Skeleton.Image/>;

  return <div>Your View Here...</div>;
}
```

Comment: Effect callback triggered on every render and fails to handle rejected Promises from  POST request. This can potentially render loop. Also, while I don't disagree that they are superior, preferring functional components over class-based components is strictly *that*, a preference. It's very opinionated. This is like taking your car to a repair shop and they tell you to fix it by buying a new car of a different brand.

Comment: Yes you're right about the `effect`, I forgot to put the `dependency array`. I used `prefer` and I know there are some rare cases which is using `class component`  makes more sense.

but this was my suggestion, as you're story tells if you're car is `olllllllllllllllld` and the shop is suggesting you to buy a new one, it's just a suggestion, you can take it or not.

there is no reason for downVoting to prof you have an idea

Comment: I only downvoted for the reasons explained in the first couple sentences since they didn't/don't fix the OP's issue and weren't/aren't correct. Sorry if the rest was interpreted negatively, I was just pointing out that *that* part of your answer seemed more a matter of opinion and didn't directly address any issue OP has. If you edit and resolve the issues in the effect I'm more than happy to revisit.

Comment: I forgot to put the dependency `[]` and you're absolutely right about it which make the code not running correctly. but I'm still saying we should go with what the community says it's a best practice and if we compare the code in question with my answer we can understand why it's cleaner and more readable.Also we need to be more kind with eachother ;) . have a nice day

Comment: No worries, I thought I was being kind by at least leaving a comment as to why a downvote. Do you know how many times I've received a downvote and no comment whatsoever so I can improve it? I think it is better to first resolve an issue using the OP's code, since it's what they are familiar with, so they can see it working, and then make the suggestion to use the cleaner code, explaining where the changes occur from their *poor* code to your *improved* code. This is an important step, IMO, in helping someone understand better coding practices. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese You're right Drew. I'm glad we had a chat together and I learned some new perspectives. Cheers